# CSS Dropdown Menu with CSS Transitions Z-Index not working

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the `z-index` to show my drop down menu above my main hero image on the homepage.

The site to visit to see it is: auldlangsynegoods.com. I am hoping somebody can use some dev tools to look at the site and figure out why this drop down isn't appearing.

Here is the clean and simple html:

```
<nav id="mainNav" role="navigation" class="cf">
    <h2>Site navigation</h2>
    <ul class="topMenu">
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Infant and Baby</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Shoes">Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Hats">Hats</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Clothing">Clothing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="millinery.html" title="Millinery Also Known as Hats">Millinery</a></li>
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Shoes and Accessories</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Mens Shoes">Mens Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Womens Shoes">Womens Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Bags">Bags</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Organic Skincare</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="Organic_Skincare.html" title="Organic Skincare - Body">Body</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Organic Skincare - Face">Face</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Garments.html" title="Garments">Garments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

And here is the simple clean CSS for the desktop view:

```
/*nav styles*/
#mainNav {
    padding-left:3.9%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

#mainNav li {
    float: left;
}

#mainNav a {

    display: block;
    color: #383420;
    border: none;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
    color: #484329;
}

#mainNav a.current {
    color: #A6A6A6;
    cursor: default;
}
/*nav styles*/
#mainNav {
    padding-left: 3.9%;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
#mainNav li {
    margin-right: 3%;
    position: relative;
}
#mainNav a, #mainNav h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
/*dropdown menu styles*/
#mainNav ul.subMenu {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 2.8em;
    left: -8000em;
    max-height: 0;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(76, 67, 65);
    background: rgba(76, 67, 65, .9);
}
#mainNav li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
    max-height: 20em;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li a:hover {
    background: rgb(123, 121, 143);
}
```

Comment: You should post a fiddle and list the steps that you have tried to fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to that fiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a start

Comment: Got it. How can I post it to this post to show users?

Comment: fill it out, then run/update/save your edits, and then post the link here.. .up in your question... not the comments

Answer (score 3):

On the website you provided it looks to be that z-index isn't the issue, but rather that you need to remove `overflow: hidden;` from:

```
#mainNav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

I was able to see the drop downs after removing that style using the chrome web dev tools.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. Such simple little things sometimes can drive me nuts.